# What is the term or word for when facts or truths, while accurate, have no bearing on the subject or argument

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term or word for when facts or truths, while accurate, have no bearing on the subject or argument: "Leaves are green in summer, therefore we should all wear boots"

Comment: Regarding being closed as duplicate, I don't think that's the case at all.  The answer to this question is not the same as the answer to that one.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Yes; that was a non-sequitur, perhaps. This is the one I was trying to find. It takes time. It's a balance, trying to stop a lot of people giving repeat answers. Did you look up 'non-sequitur' here yourself?

Comment: I'm the one who submitted it as an answer.  The other question is more closely described by the top answer, a denial of the antecedent-- which is a very different logical fallacy.  OP's question is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ["non sequitur"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur) (literally "does not follow")

> a statement (such as a response) that does not follow logically from or is not clearly related to anything previously said

Note: this phrase is not commonly known, so you'll sound smart by using it!

Comment: It has appeared in over 100 threads on ELU already.

Comment: In a community of English-language enthusiasts, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on just the title of your question, I'd say *Digressive*.

But, regarding your ask alongside the cited argument/example, I'd go with *Fallacy*.